# How to edit a big .txt file in matlab

Tags: matlab, bigdata

I have a big .txt file containing about 1,105,000 lines like this:

```
  .
  .
  .
p123 1
p43 2
p1234 1
p56 3
 .
 .
 .
```

but I want to change it to :

```
  .
  .
  .
p123.jpg 1
p43.jpg 2
p1234.jpg 1
p56.jpg 3
  .
  .
  .
```

Do you know how I can edit this file in MATLAB?

Comment: you can, but it is not advisable - something like Bash or even CMD is much better suited for this kind of simple editing.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to answer my question:d

```
fid =fopen('your_file.txt');
fid2 =fopen('your_file2.txt','w');
n = textscan(fid,'%s %s');

for i = 1:length(n{1,1})
fprintf(fid2,[n{1}{i},'.jpg ',n{2}{i},'\n']);
end
```